# Creating AngularJS directive for editing key/value pairs with separate data definition

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a directive for editing an array of data whose definition is not known beforehand.  There are two pieces to the data, first there is a definition data structure that is loaded when the page loads and looks somewhat like this:

```
[
    { 'name': 'First field',
        'type: 'String',
        'required': true,
        'default': 'x'
    },
    { 'name': 'Second field',
        'type': 'list',
        'values': ['one', 'two', 'three' ],
    }
    ... and so on
]
```

and then, when the user edits data, I use $http to load a data structure from the server that looks like this:

```
{
    'not': 'important',
    'blah': 'blah',
    ...
    'customfields': [ 
        { 
            name:'First field',
            value: 'a value'
        },
        { 
            name:'Second field',
            value: 'one'
        }
    ]
}
```

To make things worse, the name/value pairs in the customfields structure are not guaranteed to be in the same order as the definition, and might even be just a subset of the defined fields (in which case I want to show the default value if present)
Ideally, I'd like to create a AngularJS directive so that I can just add

```
<fieldeditor field='customfields' />
```

to the page and it would flesh out the HTML as needed.  I have gotten to the point where the directive looks up the definition and creates an HTML template, but I'm at a loss as to how to hook it up to the data.  Is it possible to add hooks to the directive so that I can call one function for each field when the data is being rendered and another function when the user modifies it?  Unfortunately, I can not do this in postLink as it gets called before the $http data is loadded

Comment: Do you have a plunkr for your effort so far?